# Rationalize error

Tags: numerics, number-theory, implementation-details, number-representation

The docs state that "Rationalize[x,dx] yields the rational number with smallest denominator that lies within dx of x." However, testing this out it appears to be false.

```
Rationalize[Pi, 0.1]
```

> 22 / 7

The problem is that `16 / 5` is also within `0.1` of `Pi` and has a smaller denominator.

```
N[16 / 5 - Pi]
```

> 0.0584073

How does Rationalize actually work?

Comment: Since `N[22/7 - Pi] < N[16/5 - Pi]`, I assume, that `Rationalize` tries to minimize `Abs[dx]` though within reasonable time limits. Also, as the documentation states, it has to be true that `Abs[p/q - x] < c/q^2`, where `c = 10^-4`.

Comment: Have a look [Does Mathematica get Pi wrong?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82553/does-mathematica-get-pi-wrong)

Comment: @IstvánZachar, the part you quoted with regards to 10^-4 is specific to Rationalize[x] forms.

Comment: @Louis, I'm not sure if that's relevant. Even machine precision should provide ample accuracy for this computation.

Comment: I thought this would be thus or differently, do you have a suspect?

Comment: To make a somewhat stronger statement, @Louis that past post is on no way relevant to this one (I don't think it was relevant to much of anything, to be frank).

Comment: I'd say the documentation could be worded better for the 2-argument case of `Rationalize`. There is an interplay between denominator of result, epsilon, and size of residual. If you take `dx` as replacing the default epsilon then I think the correct claim might be to the effect: `ratPi = Rationalize[N[Pi], eps]; Abs[N[Pi] - ratPi] < N[eps]/Denominator[ratPi]^2`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau What criterion does `Rationalize` use for the 2-argument case with `eps = 0`, i.e.,  `Rationalize[some_number, 0]`?  Using a few test numbers  (N[Pi], 0.1, 399847593.00000068), I tried applying your criterion to the latter, and they all evaluated to `False`.

Comment: @theorist Offhand I do not know if any criterion is used when the second arg is 0. It just works with the bit pattern in that case.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  What I've found, empirically, is that I can ensure `Rationalize` produces a rational number exactly equal to the decimal "num" if I evaluate `Rationalize[num\`z, 0]` where `z >=  2*(Length@RealDigits[num][[1]] ) + 1` (and where "num" is the actual decimal I type in). E.g., Length@RealDigits[0.39984759300000068][[1]] = 16, and `Rationalize[0.39984759300000068\`33, 0]` gives a fraction exactly equal to the decimal, but `Rationalize[0.39984759300000068\`32, 0]` does not.  I''d like to understand why that's the cutoff.