# How to get exact Rationalize of a decimal number?

Tags: conversion, number-representation

This is on *Mathematica* 11.1 on Windows 7.

I have this value `0.97646105481464028` which I'd like to get exact rational for it. I have thought that every terminating decimal number as the above could always be converted to an exact rational number? One direct way would be to write it as `97646105481464028/100000000000000000`?

My question is, how to make *Mathematica* `Rationalize` the above to an exact rational?  This is what I tried:

```
r0=0.97646105481464028;
r1=Rationalize[r0]
```

which gives

```
0.9764610548146403
```

Then I tried

```
r2=Rationalize[r0,0]
```

which gives

```
50543748/51762175
```

But the above is not an exact, because

```
r2 - r0
```

gives

```
-1.1102230246251565*10^-16
```

I read the help, and even clicked on the new nice big thumb image for the details, but I do not understand what *Mathematica* means when it says

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not understand what the `p,q,c` come from and how to use them.

In Maple I can do this:

```
  r0:=0.97646105481464028:
  r2:=convert(r0, rational,'exact');
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Maple help, FYI, on this option is the following:

> If the third argument digits is the name 'exact' then an exact
>   conversion of  float to a rational will be performed; thus Float(f, e)
>   becomes simply f*10^e.  Note that exact conversion executes much more
>   quickly than the more  sophisticated conversion.

Then I copied the above to *Mathematica* to check:

```
r0=0.97646105481464028;
maple=24411526370366007/25000000000000000;
r0-maple
```

gives

```
0.`
```

**Question**: How to get exact `Rationalize` for the above from *Mathematica*?

Comment: You can check the **Properties & Relations** section for an explanation for the meaning of `p,q,c`.

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84234)

Comment: @J.M. You do not feel that is a duplicate?

Comment: Incidentally, the main application of `Rationalize` is when you've numerically computed a rational number (or what you hope to be a rational number), and you want to obtain the true rational value from its numerical approximation. Exactly representing the specific floating-point approximation is the wrong answer to this problem.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, what Hurkyl said, which is why it's only a comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html) to find a more precise result.

```
r0 = 0.97646105481464028;
r1 = Rationalize[r0]

r2 = SetPrecision[r0, Infinity]
```

> `8795179285210031/9007199254740992`

```
r2 - r0
```

> `0.`

If you increase the [`Precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html) of your input, you can get a rational number that is closer to 0.97646105481464028.

```
Precision@r0
```

> `MachinePrecision`

```
r0 = 0.97646105481464028`100;
Precision@r0
```

> `100.`

```
r3 = SetPrecision[r0, Infinity]
```

> 17086121198925650302678220692982191831883180533886836969508025507253230621682061409501393058711047971/
>       17498005798264095394980017816940970922825355447145699491406164851279623993595007385788105416184430592

---

Comparing with your Maple result:

```
maple = 24411526370366007/25000000000000000;

N[maple, 17]
N[r2, 17]
N[r3, 17]
```

> 0.97646105481464028
>       0.97646105481464029
>       0.97646105481464028

Comment: The output from `SetAccuracy` in your answer is wrong. I get identical results from `SetAccuracy[r0, Infinity]` and `SetPrecision[r0, Infinity]` for `r0 = 0.97646105481464028;` with *Mathematica* 11.1.0. Also please see my answer below.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks for pointing that out. You are correct my `r0` had another, higher precision value.

Answer (score 7):

When you simply input `0.97646105481464028`, you do not get this number internally:

```
0.97646105481464028 // FullForm
```

> ```
> 0.9764610548146403`
> ```

Hence you can't expect any internal function to return exactly `97646105481464028/100000000000000000` from the above numeric input.

In order to preserve exact decimal representation of the original number, you need to specify explicit `Precision` or `Accuracy` (which do the same in this particular case):

```
RealDigits[0.97646105481464028`17]
RealDigits[0.97646105481464028``17]
```

> ```
> {{9, 7, 6, 4, 6, 1, 0, 5, 4, 8, 1, 4, 6, 4, 0, 2, 8}, 0}
>
> {{9, 7, 6, 4, 6, 1, 0, 5, 4, 8, 1, 4, 6, 4, 0, 2, 8}, 0}
> ```

```
FromDigits[%]
% - 97646105481464028/100000000000000000
```

> ```
> 24411526370366007/25000000000000000
>
> 0
> ```

Note that `RealDigits` drops the sign, hence in the general case you have to multiply the output of `FromDigits` by `Sign`:

```
Sign[#]*FromDigits[RealDigits[#]] &@-0.97646105481464028`17
```

> ```
> -(24411526370366007/25000000000000000)
> ```

---

> **Question**: How to get exact `Rationalize` for the above from *Mathematica*?

It depends on what do you mean under the "exact" rational representation of an *inexact* number. One approach via `RealDigits` I have given above. `Rationalize` and `SetPrecision` implement other approaches:

> `Rationalize[x,0]` gives a rational that is equivalent to `x` up to the precision of `x`
>
> `SetPrecision[x,∞]` gets a rational directly from the bitwise representation of `x`

---

In the [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141604/how-to-get-exact-rationalize-of-a-decimal-number#comment382698_141604) [Hurkyl](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5147/hurkyl) gives a concise explanation why `Rationalize` doesn't give an "exact" representation by default:

> Incidentally, the main application of `Rationalize` is when you've numerically computed a rational number (or what you hope to be a rational number), and you want to obtain the true rational value from its numerical approximation. Exactly representing the specific floating-point approximation is the wrong answer to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I've found, empirically, that I can ensure Rationalize[ ] provides an exact rational conversion of whatever decimal I enter (call it "num") if I evaluate 
Rationalize[num`z, 0] where:

$z \geq 2*\text{Length@RealDigits[num][[1]]} + 1$

E.g.,

```
Length@RealDigits[0.97646105481464028][[1]]
==>16
```

so:

```
Rationalize[0.97646105481464028`33, 0]
==>24411526370366007/25000000000000000

24411526370366007/25000000000000000==97646105481464028/100000000000000000
==>True
```

but

```
Rationalize[0.39984759300000068`32, 0]
==>5594893179322259/5729765822953714

5594893179322259/5729765822953714==97646105481464028/100000000000000000
==>False
```

I'd like to understand why that's the cutoff*, so I'll be posting my own question on that soon. [*That's the general cutoff; there are some decimals that are exactly converted with a lower value of z, but I've not found any that require a higher value for z.]

Alternately, you can also achieve an exact rational conversion using Round[num`y, 10^-y], where (again, empricially), I've found that:

$y \geq \text{Length@RealDigits[num][[1]]} + 1$

Thus:

```
Round[0.97646105481464028`17, 10^-17]
==>24411526370366007/25000000000000000
```

but

```
Round[0.39984759300000068`16, 10^-16]
==>5594893179322259/5729765822953714
```

Finally, one way to understand why SetPrecision[num`z, Infinity] won't generally give an exact rational conversion of the decimal you enter is that SetPrecision[ ] is restricted to converting "num" to that subset of rational base-10 numbers that can be represented in binary with a finite number of digits; it then pads that binary with an infinite number of zeros. And, while there are exceptions (e.g., 0.5), decimals typically can't be exactly represented with a finite binary.

Thus:

```
RealDigits[SetPrecision[0.97646105481464028`33, Infinity], 2, 300]

==>{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0}
```

and

```
Take[RealDigits[SetPrecision[0.97646105481464028`33, Infinity], 2, 
   10^9][[1]], -100]

{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

But:

```
RealDigits[Rationalize[0.97646105481464028`33, 0], 2, 300]

==>{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
  1}
```

and

```
Take[RealDigits[Rationalize[0.97646105481464028`33, 0], 2, 
   10^9][[1]], -100]

{1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}
```

You might also want to take a look at the answer by george2079 here: [Enter exact rational numbers easily with decimal notation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42141/enter-exact-rational-numbers-easily-with-decimal-notation/46169#46169)

Note also that the part of the documentation you quoted with `p,q,c` applies only to the single-argument `Rationalize[x]` forms, as noted by sn6uv here:  [Rationalize error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121025/rationalize-error).  For the dual-argument forms, `Rationalize[x, dx]` (excepting where dx = 0, which is what I was using above), Daniel Lichtblau, at that same link, says:  "I'd say the documentation could be worded better for the 2-argument case of Rationalize. There is an interplay between denominator of result, epsilon, and size of residual. If you take dx as replacing the default epsilon then I think the correct claim might be to the effect: `ratPi = Rationalize[N[Pi], eps]; Abs[N[Pi] - ratPi] < N[eps]/Denominator[ratPi]^2.`"

Answer (score 3):

You can find fractions with smaller numerators and denominators by using continued fractions.

```
r0 = 0.9764610548146402800000000000000;

s = ContinuedFraction[r0, 20]

(*{0, 1, 41, 2, 14, 41, 2, 21, 2, 10, 1, 6, 6, 1, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 2}*)

FromContinuedFraction[s]

(*2258911026868/2313365203589*)

0.97646105481464028 - 2258911026868/2313365203589

{*0*)
```

As J.M. points out below, we do not have to guess for the magical number 20.

```
Convergents[r0]
```

does everything for us.

Comment: Have you seen `Convergents[]` already?

Comment: Hi; J.M. yes I know about that but I did not think of using it. I was so excited about finding a smaller fraction. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is related to the response by @AlexeyPopkov. The idea is to use the computed base 10 digits to construct a base 10 rational approximation.

```
baseTenRationalize[num_Real] := With[
  {rd = RealDigits[num]}, {denom = 10^(Length[rd[[1]]] - rd[[2]])},
  Round[denom*num]/denom
  ]
```

A slight modification of the example in question:

```
baseTenRationalize[9.7646105481464028]

(* Out[60]= 4882305274073201/500000000000000 *)
```

This does not quite capture the last digit or so of the base 10 input. That's because we are losing a bit or so, literally, in going from decimal input to binary internal representation and back to decimal. One can force higher precision by using bignum input.

```
baseTenRationalize[9.7646105481464028`17]

(* Out[61]= 24411526370366007/2500000000000000 *)
```

Comment: What are the advantages of this approach as compared to ``FromDigits[RealDigits[9.7646105481464028`17]]``?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Probably none. What I showed might just be a longer version thereof.

Comment: 17 digit long real numbers like `0.97646105481464028` seem to be the edge case, where one loses the last digit. From my experience, every longer input gets converted to an arbitrary precision number correctly and for every shorter input machine-precision is enough. In other words: Shouldn't Mathematica convert the input `0.97646105481464028` to an arbitrary precision number with `Accuracy` 17 as it converts the input `0.976461054814640280` to a number with `Accuracy` 18?

Comment: @Karsten7. Under no circumstances should Mathematica convert a machine number into a bignum. There is a gray area, as you note, where it is not obvious that a given input cannot be represented as a machine number. I think it is better to err on the side of speed, that is, make it a machine number.

Comment: But the machine precision number input would be ``0.97646105481464028` `` according to [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html#28889). Also I was not just talking about input to Mathematica, but also input to `RealDigits`. For example `r0 = 0.12345678901234567; r1 = 0.12345678901234568;` have different `FullForm`s, but the same `RealDigits`.

Comment: @Karsten7 I may be mistaken but I think one problem is that often machine numbers are presented with 17 (as opposed to 16) digits present. I confess that offhand I do not know what is the reason for Mathematica interpreting 17 digit decimals as machine numbers, but it might be related to this.