# Find the 5566th digit after the decimal point of 7/101

Tags: number-theory

I want to find the 5566th digit after the decimal point of 7/101. I input the following code into Mathematica 11:

```
Mod[IntegerPart[7/101*10^5566], 10]
```

The output is `6`, which is the correct answer. Is there a better way to find the answer? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The best way to find this digit is in my opinion to calculate it. Since 7/101 ist periodic and so every digit in position n for which mod(n,4)=2 is 6. And mod(5566,4)=2.

Comment: @mgamer great point.  Intelligence wins over brute force.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Was about to post an answer using just that (though it's *not* as simple as just a `Mod` - one must account for possible non-repeating digits before repeat starts), but not clear if OP needs merit the extra code. It will be orders of magnitude faster when going out millions+ digits, but for less, probably no real advantage over your answer...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Fast algorithm

```
n = 5566
IntegerPart[10 Mod[7 PowerMod[10, n - 1, 101], 101]/101]
```

A brute force approach (see also these posts on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804934/getting-a-specific-digit-from-a-ratio-expansion-in-any-base-nth-digit-of-x-y) :) ) may 
be fine for the current problem, but what if `n` is a huge number? The only possibility apart from guessing the periodic sequence of numbers as mgamer suggested would be to use *modular arithmetics*. Let me explain my answer. In contrast to the original post we put the number of interest not in the last digit of the **integer part**, but in the first digit of the **fractional part**. Conveniently, the fractional part can be computed as a reminder, or for higher efficiency by `PowerMod`.

Let us compare the timing of the two methods:

```
n = 556612345;
Mod[IntegerPart[7 10^n/101], 10] // Timing
(*{10.447660, 3}*)
IntegerPart[10 Mod[7 PowerMod[10, n - 1, 101], 101]/101] // Timing
(*{0.000016, 3}*)
```

The time difference is obvious!

### Explanation

Let us consider another example, we compute the `n=6` digit of the `7/121` fraction.

```
n = 6
N[7/121, 30]
```

0.05785**1**2396694214876033057851240.

In the original post the sought digit is the last digit of the integer part:

```
N[7 10^n/121, 20]
```

5785**1**.239669421487603

whereas in my solution it is the first digit in the fractional part

```
N[Mod[7*10^(n - 1), 121]/121, 20]
```

0.**1**2396694214876033058  .

It is further used that `Mod[a 10^b,c]=Mod[a PowerMod[10,b,c],c]`.

### Reusable function

As requested in the comments, a reusable function can be provided:

```
Clear[nthDigitFraction];
nthDigitFraction[numerator_Integer, denominator_Integer, n_Integer, 
   base_Integer: 10] /; n > 0 && base > 0 && denominator != 0 := 
 Module[{a = Abs[numerator], b = Abs[denominator]}, 
  IntegerPart[base Mod[a PowerMod[base, n - 1, b], b]/b]]
```

Comment: That's the way to do it. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I provided a reusable function, feel free for improving or making it more general.

Comment: @yarchik if you looked at my code and read its introduction I DO NOT use brute force. In this case the recurring cycle is length 4 so determining digit is almost trivial. I applaud your method. Please note my function is general but not tweeted and used modular arithmetic.

Comment: @ubpdqn Thank you, I modified my post accordingly. However, if you try your method on larger numbers the computational time grows rather fast. For instance I could not have computed `dec[7, 101345, 5566]`with your method.

Comment: @yarchik yes and that is why I voted for your answer. It is very efficient and clean and was a nice lesson for me. The achilles heal  of my approach was the  need (not to process all the digits) but determing the cylce. :)

Comment: Quick question: Is there a reason for `N[Mod[7 *10^(n - 1), 121], 121]/121, 20]` to have 2 left brackets and 3 right brackets? I'm having trouble understanding what's going on here.

Comment: @Sherlock9 Thank you for spotting a misprint. Now it is corrected.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative formulation of [`RealDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealDigits.html) that I prefer:

```
RealDigits[7/101, 10, 1, -5566][[1, 1]]

(* 6 *)
```

This yields better performance which becomes important when looking for deeper digits:

```
d = 6245268;

RealDigits[7/101, 10, 1, -d][[1, 1]]  // AbsoluteTiming
RealDigits[7/101, 10, d - 1][[1, -1]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0501477, 3}
>
> {1.06702, 3}
> ```

Recommended reading:

- [Does Mathematica get Pi wrong?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82553/does-mathematica-get-pi-wrong/82605#82605)

---

For comparison to other methods now posted `RealDigits` can compute the repeating decimal itself:

```
RealDigits[7/101]
```

> ```
> {{{6, 9, 3, 0}}, -1}
> ```

How to programmatically work with this output was the subject of a different Question, though I cannot find it at the moment.  The possible combinations of repeating and nonrepeating digits as well as the offset makes a truly elegant yet robust solution difficult (at least to me) but in the *easiest* case, which this happens to be:

```
d = 5566;

RealDigits[7/101] /.
  {{c_List}, o_} :>
    c[[ Mod[d + o, Length @ c, 1] ]]

(* 6 *)
```

This is of course quite fast:

```
d = 556612345;

RealDigits[7/101] /.
  {{c_List}, o_} :> c[[ Mod[d + o, Length@c, 1] ]] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.00001243, 0}
> ```

Answer (score 9):

Use [`RealDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealDigits.html)

```
RealDigits[7/101, 10, 5566][[1]][[5565]]
```

Comment: FWIW this could also be written `RealDigits[7/101, 10, 5566 - 1][[1, -1]]`. +1 of course, but see the performance caveat in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Correction**

I thank yarchik for his answer and his test of my code identified an error (as well as my code being extremely inefficient for long cycle length):

For this particular example, the recurring patter is of length 4.

So,

```
fun[n_, d_] := 
 Module[{lst = 
    NestWhileList[QuotientRemainder[10 #[[2]], d] &, 
     QuotientRemainder[n, d], UnsameQ, All], p}, 
  p = Position[lst, lst[[-1]]][[1, 1]];
  {lst[[1 ;; p - 1, 1]], lst[[p ;; -2, 1]]}]
dec[n_, d_, p_] := Module[{a, b},
  {a, b} = fun[n, d];
  b[[Mod[p-Length@a+1, Length@b, 1]]]]
```

where

- `fun` just separates cycling and non-cycling.
- `dec` determines value of at position `p` by working out where in cycle `p` is

So,

```
dec[7, 101, 5566]
dec[7, 101, 6245268]
```

yields 6 and 3 respectively.

As a reality check (not proof):

```
{#, RealDigits[7/101, 10, 1, -#][[1, 1]], dec[7, 101, #]} & /@ 
  RandomInteger[{10000, 1000000}, 20] // TableForm
```

[image]