# How Create a list of the first 10,000 digits of Pi and sum it?

Tags: digits

I need help for a problem I m having trouble with.
I need to create a list with the first 10'000 digits of Pi and sum the digits 259 to 7233.

I managed to create a list with the following code:
list1 = RealDigits[Pi, 10, 10]

But then I am unable to do any computation with it.

Somebody can help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why create a list of 10000 digits when you are not going to use any digit beyoun digit 7223?

Comment: Why bother? It will be approximately equal to `(7233 - 259 + 1) * (0 + 9) / 2` :-)

Comment: Related: [(125025)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125025/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
RealDigits[Pi, 10, 10000] // First // Take[#, {259, 7233}] & // Total
```

Comment: Thanks it works as well!

Answer (score 7):

Does this do what you want:

```
Total @ RealDigits[Pi, 10, 10^4][[1,259;;7233]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the four-argument of form of `RealDigits`:

> - RealDigits[$x, b, len, n$] gives *len* digits starting with the coefficient of $b^n$.

```
m = 259;
n = 7233;
Total@First@RealDigits[Pi, 10, n - (m - 1), -(m - 1)]
```

> 31574

Comment: That should be `Total @ First @ RealDigits[Pi, 10, 7233 - 259 + 1, -258]` instead.

Comment: Thank you @CarlWoll. Fixed.